# bash script with case test condition

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

Hi I want to simplify my script with case

```
echo "The file $1 is "
if [ -f $1 ] then;
  echo "an regular file"
elif [ -d $1 ] then;
  echo "a directory"
fi
```

by something like this

```
case $1 in
  [ -f $1 ])
    echo "an regular file"
    ;;
  [ -d $1 ])
    echo "a directory"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: What kind of function ? Parameter ?
I don't want to use if condition but case with a lot of test on directory/file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how `case` works, in any programmming language. In `case`, you have one test/expression at the top that gives a value, and depending on that value, you can do different things. The whole point of this is that you only run your test command *once*, and not for every `elif` branch.
What you want, is just `if`/`elif` with a different syntax, which is sort of pointless...

If you want to simplify it, you might be able to use `stat`:

```
case $(stat -c%F "$1") in
  directory)
     echo Directory; ;;
  regular\ file)
     echo File; ;;
esac
```

This has (slightly) better performance than your first example, since it only runs one external command

Bonus hint: Remember to always quote filenames, so use: `[ -f "$1" ]` and **not** `[ -f $1 ]`. Consider that 1) `[` is just a shell command (a builtin or `/bin/[`, makes no real difference though), and 2) `$1` may contain spaces or other whitespace...

Comment: `[` is a built-in as well as an external program. See `type -a [`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want output like `regular file` or `directory` from a given file then use [`stat` command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stat):

```
stat -c '%F' afile.txt
regular file

stat -c '%F' adirectory
directory
```

Comment: The idea is to get a bash script with the output :

The file /etc is an directory

"/etc" is accessible by root read-write


The /etc/passwd file is a regular file that is not empty 
"/etc/passwd" is accessible by toto read.